# "word-break" does not work correctly in CSS Grid

Tags: css, firefox, word-break

I have a problem with CSS grid.

In a Firefox, when the width of the screen is reduced (eg to 600px), some elements on pages that uses CSS Grid do not support `word-break` value. They remain on the same line as they were.

I tried to add a `display: inline-block` but it didn't fix that.

That's the bug:

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
margin: 0 0;
padding: 0 0;
}

.grid {
text-align: center;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
display: grid;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

.item {
grid-area: one;
display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">
    <p>Some looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong line</p>
    <p>Some looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong line</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another example: [link](https://igorkowalczyk.github.io/majobot/?ref=stack)

[image: word-break bug]

Is there any property I have to or can use to solve this problem?

Comment: where is word-break in your code?

Comment: @Sfili_81 `word-break: break-word` is default value

Answer (score 0):

You need to Wrap your text using CSS. You can check how it works on w3schools here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap

Example code copied from above page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
  width: 150px; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

div.a {
  word-wrap: normal;
}

div.b {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The word-wrap Property</h1>

<h2>word-wrap: normal (default):</h2>
<div class="a"> This div contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</div>

<h2>word-wrap: break-word:</h2>
<div class="b"> This div contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</div>

</body>
</html>
```